# Wildfly with jaas always results in login-error

Tags: primefaces, jaas, java-ee-7, wildfly, postgresql-9.3

For some reason i can't loggin in my application using Wildfly, primefaces and JAAS. I didn't try it in others versions like JBoss 7 AS because i want to see this working on Wildfly.

After try loggin using admin for j_username and 1234 for j_password, it redirecting to login-error page. I can't understand why.

MD5 hash econding it's right with generated password from postgres

I can acess this JDNI and execute some querys from java code, concluding it's working.

```
String DATASOURCE_CONTEXT = "java:jboss/datasources/zephyrplace-ds";

        Connection result = null;
        try {
          Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
          if ( initialContext == null){
            System.out.println("JNDI problem. Cannot get InitialContext.");
          }
          DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
          if (datasource != null) {
            result = datasource.getConnection();
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Failed to lookup datasource.");
          }
        }
        catch ( NamingException ex ) {
          System.out.println("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
          System.out.println("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
        }
        return result;
```

login.xhtml (primefaces):

```
<h:form id="login" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';" prependId="false">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>    
            <center>
                <p:inputText name="j_username" placeholder="Usuario" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;" size="15" id="user" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.usuario}" rendered="#{empty usuarioBean.usuarioLogado}"></p:inputText>
            </center>
        </li>
        <li>
            <center>
                <p:inputText id="j_password" name="j_password" placeholder="Senha" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;" size="15" type="password" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.senha}" rendered="#{empty usuarioBean.usuarioLogado}"></p:inputText>
            </center>
        </li>
        <li>
            <center>
                <p:commandButton style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;" value="Entrar" rendered="#{empty usuarioBean.usuarioLogado}" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
            </center>
        </li>
    </ul>
</h:form>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
<security-domain>zephyrplace-security-domain</security-domain> 
</jboss-web>
```

standalone.xml:

```
<security-domains>
    <security-domain name="zephyrplace-security-domain" cache-type="default">
                        <authentication>
                            <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                                <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/zephyrplace-ds"/>
                                <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select pass from users where name=?"/>
                                <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role_name from user_roles where user_name = ?"/>
                                <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                                <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base16"/>
                            </login-module>
                        </authentication>
                    </security-domain>
                </security-domains>
```

postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE "users"
(
  "name" character varying(50),
  pass character varying(50)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "users" OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE user_roles
(
  user_name character varying(50),
  role_name character varying
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE user_roles OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO users("name", pass) VALUES ('admin', MD5('1234'));
INSERT INTO user_roles(user_name, role_name) VALUES ('admin', 'ADMIN');
```

web.xml:

```
     <!-- Protected Areas -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Only admins</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Users and admins</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/index/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>


    <!-- Allowed Roles -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>


  <!-- Login Prompt -->   
  <login-config>           
       <auth-method>FORM</auth-method> 
       <form-login-config>  
            <form-login-page>/login/login.xhtml</form-login-page>  
            <form-error-page>/login/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>  
       </form-login-config>  
  </login-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my application i use also wildfly and i configurated the security on the standalone-full.xml. Also on rolesQuery i gave 'Roles' for the name of the result of the query. Sorry for my english. This way is better to explain:

```
<module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role_name, 'Roles' from user_roles where user_name = ?"/>
```

it think it needs that name. those are the differences i see.